# 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then')' on API request

Tags: javascript, react-hooks

My page brake when i make an request to an API, i receive the contents and it prints on the console.

```
function getFilms() {
  fetch('https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/films')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
      console.log(data);
      return data;
    });
}
export default getFilms;
```

I've tried to use a implicit return and return outside of the '.them' without success.

Comment: Could you add the code that calls this function (getFilms) ?

Comment: where are you running the code and how are you importing the module in the calling file? Just tried it in firefox console and it seems to work

Answer (score 1):

I was receiving undefined because the the caller didn't received the return of the API. Solved by returing the fetch.

```html
function getFilms() {
  return fetch('https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/films')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
      console.log(data);
    });
}
export default getFilms;
```